# Modify Android apps at runtime

Tags: java, android, bytecode-manipulation

I'm trying to modify Android apps at runtime using bytecode modification. I know it is possible modify .class files created before app is executed, but I would like to modify it while app is running. I'm not sure if it is possible or not. I have seen [ASMDEX](http://asm.ow2.org/asmdex-index.html) like a possible tool to do so, but it is based on Dalvik VMs and I don't know if it works fine in ART VMs, I think no. In fact, I'm not so sure it can modify apps at runtime.

Is possible to modify Android apps at runtime using bytecode modification? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In JVM you can use JavaAgents to achieve this but since android used Dalvik, that is not an option. However Android has support for [instrumentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html). You can use the [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method to modify the application before has been loaded. This will likely need root access.